# mysql order by some condition and case insensitive

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to sort order

"special character - number - alphabet - others - space"

and using this query

```
SELECT title FROM table ORDER BY 
    (case when ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) = 0 then 9
        when (ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) >= 33 and ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) <= 47) then 1
        when (ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) >= 58 and ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) <= 64) then 2
        when (ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) >= 91 and ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) <= 96) then 3
        when (ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) >= 123 and ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) <= 126) then 4
        when (ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) >= 48 and ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) <= 57) then 5
        when ASCII(SUBSTRING(title, 1)) > 128 then 7
        when ASCII(SUBSTRING(title,1)) = 32 then 8
        else 6 end ),binary(title)";
```

I have the desired result with this query.

but onething,

alphabet order result is (A, B, C , a, b ,c)

I want result as (A, a, B, b, C, c)

How can I get that?

Comment: this approach is only doing your special logic for the first character, not any of the later characters, so e.g. "A " will sort before "AB" even though space should come after B

Comment: `when (ASCII(SUBSTRING(UPPER(title), 1)) ..`

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult to do what you want.  I would suggest relaxing your constraints a little and and just following ascii order except changing spaces to some high character:

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(title,' ',CONVERT(_utf32 0x10FFFF USING utf8mb4)),BINARY(title);
```